# Delete a Job and wait until job is deleting in client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, jobs, client-go

```golang
// Delete a Batch Job by name
func (k K8sClient) DeleteBatchJob(name string, namespace string) error {
    return k.K8sCS.BatchV1().Jobs(namespace).Delete(context.TODO(), name, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
}
```

I am deleting a job if already exists and then starting a new Job, but the operation here is asynchronous and job creation phase started when the job is being deleted, which I don't want.
I want to successfully delete a job before creation of new one.

How can I implement this functionality using go?

Comment: do you already have check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63443470/use-client-go-to-simulate-kubectl-wait-for-a-pod-to-be-ready

Comment: Create jobs with a unique name.  Use labels to identify instead of trusting name

Comment: Sounds a good idea, Thanks a lot for quick review

Comment: Hi @DanielFarrell, could you post your solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you give every job a unique name, you won't have to wait for the asynchronous deletion to make a new one.  This is how the cron scheduler works in k8s - it creates uniquely named jobs every time.

To find and manage the jobs, you can use labels instead of the job name.